# Tabular form validation without submitting

Tags: oracle-apex

In APEX 3.2, I want to be able to run JavaScript validations to check the data entered and display the appropriate message above each row in the tabular form.

I'm not sure how this would work given that it is a tabular form and the user will be able to add/delete rows.

Appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, doing some javascript validations on tabular forms is a bit complex, and you need to know what you're doing.

First off, you will need to know the ids or names of the elements you wish to check. As you may know, elements in tabular forms are stored in arrays in apex on submit, and are accessed through `apex_application.g_f01/g_f02/...` 
This is reflected in the html code, and the generated elements also have the attribute 'name' set to the column they belong to. The id also holds the column, plus the rowindex. Warning though, this id is only generated like this when the item is created 'implicitly', ie you did not write your query with apex_item calls (`apex_item.textbox(...)`).

Another but is that only fields of which the state is saved will have an array column defined. An item which you'd only show as 'display only', will not be generated with an input tag, and will just be held as text in a td tag.

All by all, when you know that, the next steps should be straightforward enough. Take a look at the page source, and take a note of the elements you wish to target. For example, i went for the job field.

```
<tr class="highlight-row">
<td headers="CHECK$01" class="data"><label for="f01_0003" class="hideMeButHearMe">Select Row</label><input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="3" class="row-selector" id="f01_0003" /></td>
<td headers="EMPNO_DISPLAY" class="data">7782</td>
<td headers="ENAME" class="data"><label for="f03_0003" class="hideMeButHearMe">Ename</label><input type="text" name="f03" size="12" maxlength="2000" value="CLARK"  id="f03_0003" /></td>
<td headers="JOB" class="data"><label for="f04_0003" class="hideMeButHearMe">Job</label><input type="text" name="f04" size="12" maxlength="2000" value="MANAGER"  id="f04_0003" /></td>
<td headers="HIREDATE" class="data"><label for="f05_0003" class="hideMeButHearMe">Hiredate</label><span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="text"  id="f05_0003" name="f05" maxlength="2000" size="12" value="09-JUN-81" autocomplete="off"></span></td>
<td headers="SAL" class="data">
   <label for="f06_0003" class="hideMeButHearMe">Sal</label><input type="text" name="f06" size="16" maxlength="2000" value="2450"  id="f06_0003" />
   <input type="hidden" name="f02" value="7782"  id="f02_0003" />
   <input type="hidden" id="fcs_0003" name="fcs" value="19BD045E01D6BA148B4DEF9DDC8B21B7">
   <input type="hidden" id="frowid_0003" name="frowid" value="AAuDjIABFAAAACTAAC" />
   <input type="hidden" id="fcud_0003" name="fcud" value="U" />
</td>
</tr>
```

In the javascript section of the page i then added the following 2 functions.

validate_job does the validation of just one field, the element elJob. The validation i used is just very basic, it's up to you to determine just how complex you want it.

If you want to reference other fields in the same row here, you can do several things: extract the rowindex from the id, if you have it. If it doesn't hold the it, get the parent TR, and then use `.children("input[name='f##'")` to get an input element in the same row. Or if you need the value of an item which does not save state at all, you'll need to get the TR element, and then find the TD which contains the element you need through the headers attribute, which holds the column name.

```
function validate_job(elJob){
   var sJob = $v(elJob).toUpperCase();
   $(elJob).val(sJob);

   //do your validations for the field job here
   if(sJob=="MANAGER"){
      $(elJob).css({"border-color":"red"});
      alert("invalid value!");
      //depends what you want to do now:
      //keep the focus on this element? Set a flag an error occured? Store the error?      
      return false;
   } else {
      $(elJob).css({"border-color":""});
      alert("value ok");                
        };
};
```

Call bind_validations onload. If you allow rows to be created, bind a click event to the addrow button and call bind_validations.

```
function bind_validations(){
   //f01 : row selector
   //f03 : ename
   //f04 : job
   //f05 : hiredate
   //f06 : sal

    //each input element with attribute name with value f04
   //blur event is when the user leaves the field, fe tab out, or even click apply changes
   //much like how when-validate-item behaved in forms
   $("input[name='f04']").blur(function(){validate_job(this);});
};
```

Just a proper warning though. I've used javascript validations in some apps so far, but i knew they were only going to be used by a small number of people, and then only internally. It was only one field, with some validations. I made the cursor refocus on the field when the validation failed, so they couldn't jump to the next record and change that aswell. Either a valid value was given, or they reloaded the page or canceled the action. Set up like this, they can't press apply changes either, as the blur event would also fire, validating the field.

When your audience is larger, it gets a bit more iffy: what i javascript is disabled? What if they find some way around? Wizzkids?

I still like the immediate feedback it gives, but in a more critical environment i'd also use the server-side validations. To do this, you need a validation of the type "function returning error text". Check out [this page](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=31517:190:4222499025822041%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a) for an example, or [this one](http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/plug-play-tabular-form-handling/) for some usefull tips (at least for pre 4.0!). Also: apex 4.1 really improves a lot on tabular form validations! ;)